# Pasting two strings using paste function and its collapse argument

Tags: r, string

I am trying to paste two vectors

```
vector_1 <- c("a", "b") 
vector_2 <- c("x", "y") 
paste(vector_1, vector_2, collapse = " + ")
```

The output I get is

```
"a + b x + y "
```

My desired output is

```
"a + b + x + y"
```

Comment: Your output doesn't match what I get; when I run your code output is "a x + b y". Does `paste(c(list_1,list_2),collapse="+")` solve your issue?

Comment: yeah I believe it does solve the issue. Thank you @Heroka

Comment: Also this works: `paste(list_1, list_2, collapse = " + ", sep=" + ")`

Comment: @digEmAll Thank you, Guess this works too. I will just go with the first one  since I need to maintain some order.

Comment: maybe you should also title the question, "pasting two vectors"

Comment: @MattO'Brien I appreciate the interest. I believe I have got an answer for what I was searching for and by looking at the code it is quite evident to any R user the request and the motive of my question. In case if you feel it is not that easy for a learner to understand my question, please feel free to edit it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`paste` with more then one argument will paste together term-by-term.

```
> paste(c("a","b","c"),c("A","B","C"))
[1] "a A" "b B" "c C"
```

the result being  the length of the longest vector, with the shorter term recycled. That enables things like this to work:

```
> paste("A",c("1","2","BBB"))
[1] "A 1"   "A 2"   "A BBB"
> paste(c("1","2","BBB"),"A")
[1] "1 A"   "2 A"   "BBB A"
```

then `sep` is used *within* the elements and `collapse` to join the elements.

```
> paste(c("a","b","c"),c("A","B","C"))
[1] "a A" "b B" "c C"
> paste(c("a","b","c"),c("A","B","C"),sep="+")
[1] "a+A" "b+B" "c+C"
> paste(c("a","b","c"),c("A","B","C"),sep="+",collapse="@")
[1] "a+A@b+B@c+C"
```

Note that once you use `collapse` you get a single result rather than three.

You seem to not want to combine your two vectors element-wise, so you need to turn them into one vector, which you can do with `c()`, giving us the solution:

```
> c(vector_1, vector_2)
[1] "a" "b" "x" "y"
> paste(c(vector_1, vector_2), collapse=" + ")
[1] "a + b + x + y"
```

Note that `sep` isn't needed - you are just collapsing the individual elements into one string.

Comment: Thank you :) I understand it :) In fact the comments section had given me a desired answer. Your answer gave me a clear understanding of the collapse argument.